# Python natural spline function cr in patsy only accepts 3 or more degrees of freedom, whereas ns in R accepts 2

Tags: python, r, spline, patsy

I am trying to port this functionality into python

```
> x <- 0:10
> y <- x**2
> lm(y ~ ns(x,df=2))
```

Such as:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

x = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(11))
y = x**2
formula="y ~ cr(x, df = 3)"

reg = smf.ols(formula,data=x).fit()
print(res.summary())
```

However with this python formulation, I cannot set df<3. Any suggestions how I can have a natural spline in python with two degrees of freedom, and use it in patsy as an R style equation?

Comment: I would inspect (probably graphically) the basis matrices generated by these two approaches.  Are they both *natural* splines (i.e. linear constraints at the boundaries)? Do they both include or exclude the intercept term?

Comment: Is this a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71550468/does-python-have-an-analogue-to-rs-splinesns

Answer (score 0):

These are clearly generating different bases: I'm not sure what the difference is, but the exploration below might help.

Note that `cr` mimics the basis construction from `mgcv` (see [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mgcv/versions/1.8-41/topics/smooth.construct.cr.smooth.spec); in addition to Simon Wood's book they are also discussed [here](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-019-0666-3)), while `ns()` is a natural spline built on a B-spline basis. I believe that `splines::bs()` and `patsy.bs` would match perfectly, but there is no `patsy.ns`.

```r
x <- 0:10
X1 <- model.matrix(~splines::ns(x, df = 3))
matplot(x, X1, type = "l")
```

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import patsy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(11)
X2 = patsy.dmatrix(
        'cr(x, df = 3)',
        {'x': x}, return_type='dataframe')
plt.plot(X2)
```

[image]